# How to handle multiple bindings of log4j in a Scala project?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j, slf4j, log4j2

I am working on a Spark project.
Now I want to import a library `elastic4s`. In sbt config file, I use:

```
val elastic4sVersion = "5.4.5"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
                         "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-core" % elastic4sVersion,
                         // for the tcp client
                         "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-tcp" % elastic4sVersion,

                         // for the http client
                         "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-http" % elastic4sVersion).map(_.force())
//exclusion
libraryDependencies ~= { _.map(_.exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12")) }
```

When without the exclusion of `log4j`, when i excute:

```
val client = HttpClient(ElasticsearchClientUri("localhost", 9200))
```

Error occurs:

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/junlang/spark-2.2.0/MySpark/assembly/target/scala-2.11/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/junlang/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
>   SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
>   log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.HttpClient$).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>   log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Seems my Spark source code includes `log4j` too and that leads to a multiple bindings exception.

Then I add the exclusion code in sbt config file, and another error occurs:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.HttpClient$).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>   log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

This makes me so upset....
Really need your help!~~~~

Comment: Complement: When i use HttpClient, there is another error: `Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V`.  I searched my dependencies, there exists the `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3`. So i am confused.

Comment: are there two versions of `httpclient` in classpath? check spark logs when you submit job it prints spark classpath. `SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND=true  ${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-shell`